# Why is scrolling jumpy right after a jQuery scrollTop?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'm using

```
$('html, body').animate({'scrollTop':target});
```

The animation is fine but when the user attempts to scroll the page "shakes" for a few seconds before it lets the user scroll again.

I can't really see anything added to the body or html tags that could cause this. I'm clearing styles from both to be sure but it still happens.

Comment: provide your html please or make a fiddle

Comment: The code is far to large at this point to post to jsfiddle. Otherwise, that would have been the first thing I do.

Comment: for some reason it looks like placing .stop() before that animation fixes the issue... ?